# "AttributeError: closed" when try to use vi to open a file

Tags: python, linux, vim

I got the following error when I tried to use vi to open a file. It was working fine until I installed anaconda today. Is there a way to fix this problem? Thank you!

```
   Edamame$ vi myTest.py 
    Error detected while processing /Users/edamame/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/autoload/jedi.vim:
    line  344:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/edamame/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/initialize.py", line 21, in <module>
        import jedi_vim
      File "/Users/edamame/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi_vim.py", line 27, in <module>
        import jedi
      File "/Users/edamame/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
        from jedi.api import Script, Interpreter, NotFoundError, set_debug_function
      File "/Users/edamame/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/api/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
        from jedi.parser import Parser, load_grammar
      File "/Users/edamame/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/parser/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
        from jedi.parser import tree as pt
      File "/Users/edamame/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/parser/tree.py", line 39, in <module>
        from jedi import cache
      File "/Users/edamame/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/cache.py", line 32, in <module>
        from jedi import debug
      File "/Users/edamame/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/debug.py", line 17, in <module>
        init()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/colorama/initialise.py", line 37, in init
        wrap_stream(orig_stdout, convert, strip, autoreset, wrap)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/colorama/initialise.py", line 76, in wrap_stream
        convert=convert, strip=strip, autoreset=autoreset)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 67, in __init__
        strip = conversion_supported or (not wrapped.closed and not is_a_tty(wrapped))
    AttributeError: closed
    Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: Well, the problem is in the Jedi Vim plugin; seems like something related to colour support? You can disable the plugin for a "work-around" to at leat get Vim starting. This is perhaps something you may be better off reporting at the project's bug tracker. Please post a link to the issue here! So people can check up on it and see if it's already fixed before trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Also, are you sure you're running Linux? Because `/Users/edamame/` doesn't sound very Linux-y to me?

Comment: It is in Mac. Does it make difference?